# Ember JS best way to show a full screen loading screen button press

Tags: ajax, ember.js, loading

I'm new with Ember and I would like to show a full screen overlay when a user presses a "get stuff from the server" button.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Does Ember already provide something built-in? Or is it that the only way is to have a piece of HTML in one of my templates, to show/hide it when the promise where I make the AJAX call returns?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options available to you.

The first concerns a route change.  Conventionally speaking, if the user is hitting a button that transitions to another route, [a separate route can be created to handle this in-between loading experience](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

To describe this briefly, if you have a route named `foo`, creating a sibling route named `foo-loading` with an associated template, will show a "foo-loading" page state while things are being fetched, and then dismiss it once things are good.

Alternatively, as you've hinted, if the call to action for a user intends an updated result on the same route, a loading service could be useful.  In your application template, you could have a loading div that is hidden by default.  Prior to initiating an AJAX request, you could turn the loading state on and reveal the loading div.  Then, once the AJAX call is settled, the `finally` block could include a call to conceal the loading div.

This latter approach would involve a conditionally loaded block in the primary application template, a loading service handling show and hide, and a loading template.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ember-modal-dialog](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog) to create a loading screen component that gets rendered when you're waiting for your ajax request.

For example:

```
// view.js
showLoadingScreen: true

// view.html
{{#if showLoadingScreen}}
  {{loading-screen}}
{{/if}}

// loading-screen.html
{{#ember-modal-dialog}}
  <div class="loader-full-screen-class"></div>
{{/modal-dialog}}
```

The advantage of the component/ember-modal-dialog is that this pattern is usually implemented as a modal, and this library is the standard in ember. The component then allows you to put it anywhere you need it to be.